# NoSQL without HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigtable, bigdata, nosql

HBASE builds on the top of HDFS for historical reasons; it just so happens that HBASE is a clone of Google Big Table that in turn depended on GFS and so there it is HDFS. HBASE doesn't need big parts of HDFS, but it relies on HDFS for implementing redundancy.

I read that, on principle, it would have been easier if HBASE implemented redundancy itself (i.e. without HDFS), as other NoSQL databases do.

Questions:

1) What are examples of NoSQL databases that implement redundancy without relying on HDFS?

2) If HDFS is not in use, there will be another distributed file system or such NoSQL databases are doing all by themselves on the top of existing local file systems across the cluster?

3) Summing up, is possible to have a NoSQL database without a distributed file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, actually there are a lot of them, such as `Cassandra`/`MongoDB`/`Aerospike`.
2) They are `are doing all by themselves on the top of existing local file systems across the cluster`.
3) Same as `question 2)`. It's possible, the NoSQL database maintain redundancy itself.